# Jquery disable checkbox on radio button click with ASP.NET RadioButtonList

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I'd like to enable or disable a checkbox based on a radio button selection using **Jquery**, however I am struggling to find the value of the clicked radio.

The radio button list looks like this

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbRadioButton" runat="server"></asp:RadioButtonList>
```

It has no items cause those are being loaded off an enum

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            rbRadioButton.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyModel.ModelEnum));                
            rbRadioButton.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

I am using a **master page**, so I'll have to find the right ID for the controls also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to bind the inputs themselves

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#<%= rbRadioButton.ClientID %> input').change(function () {
        // The one that fires the event is always the
        // checked one; you don't need to test for this
        alert($(this).val());
    });
});
```

Just make sure that Id of the table containing radio button list is "rbRadioButton" because if some some kind of master page is used then Id of this would change to something like "MainContent_rbRadioButton". To find out the Id just open view source of the page in the browser and find rbRadioButton.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thank you, in fact I forgot to mention I am using a master page. Would something like `$(<%= rbRadioButton.ClientID %> + ' input').change(function () {` be valid to make the function container-aware? I'll try the code asap

Comment: I have updated my answer w.r.t "rbRadioButton.ClientID". please try this.

Comment: @Alexander, Did you try this solution?

Comment: Yes, brilliant. I edited your code to disable the checkbox on radio click, but I should also check if I should disable the checkbox on document ready. Here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/8qpxd7n5/

Comment: Also is there any particular reason to use `.change` instead of `.on('change'` ?

Comment: No, no particular reason to use it this way.